# SwiftUI: ForEach of FetchedResults gives the error - "Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member..."

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI and partially to Swift, so hope someone can shed some light on something I am blatantly missing. Excuse the messy code! I haven't had chance yet to refactor.

I'm using a `@FetchRequest` property wrapper to pull a list of all `Memories` back from a `CoreData` model, with a `NSFetchRequest<Memory>` method defined on it, extending from `NSManagedObject`.

When I iterate through the results of the `FetchRequest<Memory>` in SwiftUI via a `ForEach`, it returns an instance of `NSManagedObject` into the loop variable and not of `Memory`, and thus displays the error: `Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'createdAt'` for the following SwiftUI class:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MemoryView: View {

    @Environment(
        \.managedObjectContext
    ) var managedObjectContext

    @FetchRequest(
        fetchRequest: Memory.allMemories()
    ) var allMemories: FetchedResults<Memory>

    @State private var newMemory = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("What's on your mind?")) {
                    HStack {
                        TextField("New memory", text: self.$newMemory)

                        Button(action: {
                            let memory = Memory(context: self.managedObjectContext)

                            memory.title = self.newMemory
                            memory.createdAt = Date()

                            do {
                                try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                            } catch {
                                print(error)
                            }

                            self.newMemory = ""
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .imageScale(.large)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .font(.headline)

                Section(header: Text("My Memories")) {
                    ForEach(self.allMemories) { memoryItem in
                        MemoryRow(title: memoryItem.title, createdAt: memoryItem.createdAt)
                        //               /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\            /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\ /\
                        // >>> Error:
                        // >>> Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'createdAt'
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Memories"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }
}

struct MemoryView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MemoryView()
    }
}
```

And for reference, the `Memory` model in question is as follows:

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreData
import CoreLocation

// Define the CoreData Object Model.
// Ensuring that this class name matches
// the entity model name.
public class Memory: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var body: String?

    @NSManaged public var latitude: Double
    @NSManaged public var longitude: Double

    @NSManaged public var createdAt: Date?
    @NSManaged public var updatedAt: Date?

//    @NSManaged public var type: Type?
//    @NSManaged public var tags: [Tags]?
}

// Create an extension in which to place things out of the context
// of the initial class declaration within.
extension Memory {
    // Define a helper method for accessing a generated
    // CLLocationCoordinate2D instance from the objects
    // latitude and longitude values.
    var locationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude
        )
    }

    // Define a helper method that grabs all instances of a Memory
    // sorted by their created date in ascending order.
    static func allMemories() -> NSFetchRequest<Memory> {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Memory> = Memory.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Memory>

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)

        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        return request
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I am all out of ideas. A fresh head for tomorrow's problem me thinks!

Edit: Here is the `MemoryRow` class:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MemoryRow: View {
    var title: String = ""
    var createdAt: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.headline)

                Text(createdAt)
                    .font(.caption)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MemoryRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MemoryRow(title: "Test Title", createdAt: "Test Date")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `MemoryRow` ?

Comment: Also, did you check that `memoryItem` is a `Memory` object, and not an `NSManagedObject` ?

Comment: Its a another SwiftUI class, that I split out into a component to render the row. I've edited my answer!

Comment: How would I go about checking, or forcing, the object type? Xcode is reporting that the `memoryItem` is an instance of `NSManagedObject` when interfacing with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm actually a little confused as to what solved this issue for me. Here are a few things I did before it *'just worked'*.

I don't know which one caused it, I just re-opened Xcode and the previously failing build was now building again *unexpectedly*.

So, in a haste to think what I did to fix it and using the Git diffs as some form of reference, this is me re-tracing my steps, in this order:

1. Checked the View attachement in the `SceneDelegate` for the `contentView`, for which `View` the `NSManagedObjectContext` context is exposed onto. This was against the wrong `View` for me, it was attached to `MemoryDetail()` not `MemoryList()`.
2. Deleted the offending line:

```swift
MemoryRow(title: memoryItem.title!, createdAt: memoryItem.description)
```

and replacing it with just a filler `Text("test")`, saving and building the project successfully.

3. Changing the `sortDescriptor` declaration from:

```swift
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)

request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
```

to

```swift
request.sortDescriptors = [
    NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)
]
```

4. Restarting Xcode (although did this multiple times to no avail during anyway).
5. Staging, not committing, my tracked code changes.
6. Deleting the filler `Text("test")` and manually typing back out the line:

```swift
MemoryRow(title: memoryItem.title!, createdAt: memoryItem.description)
```

In which code hint still does not work, but the line now builds fine, so you have to manually do it. And no, the unwrap force `!` was not the cause of the error.

---

## EDIT:

After using Git diffs and pasting in my original code, I think I know what the error is:

```swift
MemoryRow(title: memoryItem.title!, createdAt: memoryItem.createdAt)
//                                                        ^^^^^^^^^
// This is wrong ----------------------------------------//////////
```

It doesn't help as the error the compiler gives isn't directly relational to the actual problem. The error should be that `memoryItem.createdAt` isn't returning the correct type expected by the `MemoryRow`.

```swift
MemoryRow(title: memoryItem.title!, createdAt: "")
// Compiles fine

// And now the corrected version:
MemoryRow(title: memoryItem.title!, createdAt: "\(memoryItem.createdAt!)")
```

I think the problem is Xcode's somewhat hap-hazard errors sometimes.

I've since amended the `MemoryRow` to now accept a `Date?` type instead of `String?` to actually better describe what the object is accepting. Along with unwrapping, formatting and presenting the variables within that class.

Comment: I would be careful with forced unwrapping the properties. better is to do something like `if let title = memoryItem.title, let createdAt = memoryItem.createdAt { MemoryRow(title, createdAt) }`

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, this was just a prototype stage. I'm changing that logic anyway and doing the un-wrapping within the SwiftUI component class, just to keep contextual.

Comment: yes, it's very annoying - it just says like "error" when you have an incorrect field!

Answer (score 17):

In my case, it was because of the `optional` data type which is by default selected when we add an attribute in data model and therefore in `NSManagedObjectClass` it looks like this

`@NSManaged public var name: String?`

and of course, to resolve this one can either remove `?` from the above line or use `??` nil coalescing operator when using that attribute like `ClassName.name ?? "Unknown"`

From the given answers and comments I went to check my attribute name in class for any typo and then I realised the issue. For now have to deal with this behaviour of `SwiftUI` that it won't show the actual error or will show on any other line.

Hope this can help someone like me.

Comment: bruv I had the same issue!  In my case I had unchecked the optional checkbox in xcode but for some reason the generated class still had a optional.  Not sure if I had something wrong.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

set NSManagedObject type in closure argument.

```
ForEach(books, id: \.self) { book in 
     //
}
```

to

```
ForEach(books, id: \.self) { (book: Book) in
     //
}
```

Comment: This actually works! So weird. Works on other projects with similar app designs.

Comment: Here to say this still works. Solves six esoteric error messages at once. Pasting the most relevant here to help others find this answer.

Cannot convert value 'characters' of type 'FetchedResults<>' to expected type 'Binding<FetchRequest<>.Configuration>', use wrapper instead

Initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' requires that 'FetchRequest<>.Configuration' conform to 'MutableCollection'

Cannot convert value of type 'KeyPath<_, ID>' to expected argument type 'KeyPath<FetchRequest<>.Configuration.Element, ID>'

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the type (memoryItem: Memory) of the element of the array you will be iterating over, example : .ForEach(self.allMemories) { (memoryItem: Memory) in `:

specify the Memory type here:

```
`
ForEach(self.allMemories) { (memoryItem: Memory) in
 MemoryRow(title: memoryItem.title, createdAt: memoryItem.createdAt)
     }
`
```

This is because it could be any type of NSManagedObject, but in order for Swift to know exactly what type of managed object it is we need to be explicit. checkout: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem like this:

```
var D: [ACoreDataEntity]
```

and then

```
filtered = D.filter{$0.name == 'john'}
```

Name is correctly a field of `ACoreDataEntity`

But it just wouldn't parse or compile.

## Adding braces fixed it (!)

```
filtered = L.filter{($0).name == 'john'}
```

Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this construction for fetch request

```
@FetchRequest(
    entity: Memory.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [
        NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Memory.createdAt, ascending: true)
    ]
) var allMemories: FetchedResults<Memory>
```

Comment: Ok, then return to the question about MemoryRow interface. Could you show it?

Comment: Sorry just had a sprint meet to get to. Edited my original question with it, thank you!

Comment: Probably the reason is in mismatched types, MemoryRow has String, but data object has String? and Date?. So try to align types.

Comment: Tried that, no luck. Aligned the models and its still throwing the same error:
`Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'title' or 'createdAt'`

Comment: I've since had a look at other projects that do a similar thing, implement in the same way. This project builds fine:
https://github.com/andrewcbancroft/BlogIdeaList-SwiftUI
Where as my project, that uses the exact same implementation, does not. I've tried even copying across all the methods and classes into my project from the working example, and it still doesn't work. I think I'm just going to have to start from scratch. Something has bugged and I have no idea what. Hopefully then diff'ing the projects will show what I've done wrong.

Comment: Double check your data model and make sure that all the names and types exactly match what you have in `Memory`.

Comment: You were right about the types @Asperi, although not what was being error'd, it was actually the root of the problem. Fixing the types either sent to or accepted by `MemoryRow` fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way to handle this problem is to do this

Change

```
MemoryRow(title: memoryItem.title, createdAt: memoryItem.createdAt)
```

to

```
MemoryRow(title: (memoryItem.title ?? ""), createdAt: (memoryItem.createdAt ?? ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had what looked like the very same error.

In my case I have a CoreData entity "Category" which has a one-to-many relationship with a "Contact" entity. Contact has `firstName` and `lastname` optional string properties.

My exact error was :

`Value of type 'NSObject' has no member 'lastName'` when trying to access the contact.lastName in my SwiftUI Text view.

### Solution

The solution seems to be simpler than I assumed at first, because I was reading too much into the set vs Array when this was all unneccesary:

(NOTE: This code is inside of an `if category.contacts?.count != 0 { }` as I only want to display the list if there is something to display.)

```
if category.contacts?.count != 0 {
    List {
        Section (header: Text("Contacts")) {
            ForEach(contacts) { contact in
                HStack (spacing: 4) {
                    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")
                    Text("\(contact.firstName ?? "")")
                    Text("\(contact.lastName ?? "")")
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
}
```

The beginning of this struct initializes the `contacts` like this:

```
struct CategoryForm: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var moc
    
    @ObservedObject var category: Category
    
    @State private var isEditing = false
    
    @State private var errorAlertIsPresented = false
    @State private var errorAlertTitle = ""
    
    @FetchRequest var contacts: FetchedResults<Contact>
    
    init(category: Category) {
        self.category = category
        var predicate: NSPredicate?
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category = %@", category)
        self._contacts = FetchRequest<Contact>(
            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor( keyPath: \Contact.lastName, ascending: true),
                              NSSortDescriptor( keyPath: \Contact.firstName, ascending: true)],
            predicate: predicate
        )
        
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
///etc...
```

#### My incorrect, though logical beginner code

This error for me came from looking to much at changing an NSSet into an array. But the FetchRequest is a different thing. So, simpler was better for me.

```
///This line of code generated the error!
///The Text("\(contact.firstName ?? "")") was not actually the problem
///although that line is where Xcode showed the error

ForEach(Array(category.contacts! as Set), id: \.self) { contact in

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this type of error by changing **Codegen** from **Class Definition** to **Category/Extension** in Xcode dat model.

[image]